# CDIIntegrationService errors were found when Weblogic upgrade from 12.1.2 to 12.1.3

Tags: cdi, java-7, weblogic12c

I have upgraded Weblogic version in linux server by changing the wl_home path in the setDomainEnv.sh for 12.1.2 to 12.1.3 and restart. when restarting it gives below errors.
Appreciate if anyone can give idea about this.

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.bea.logging.LogBufferHandler.bufferLogObject(Ljava/lang/Object;)V from class weblogic.logging.log4j.WLLog4jMemoryBufferAppender
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.diagnostics.lifecycle.LoggingServerService
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.diagnostics.lifecycle.DiagnosticFoundationService errors were found
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.diagnostics.lifecycle.DiagnosticFoundationService
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIIntegrationService errors were found
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIIntegrationService

Answer (score -1):

Use the wllog4j.jar which is part of WLS 12.1.3 build. The one part of WLS_HOME/server/lib diretory.

If your domains-home/lib folder holds older wllog4.jar which was part of 12.1.2 then you will face this issue